# How to weave the words of a string into a block of strings in vim?

Tags: text-processing, vim, editors

Given a string and a block of strings e.g.

String:

```
Use three words.
```

Block:

```
This is the first string of another block of strings.
This is the second string of another block of strings.
This is the third string of another block of strings.
```

Now I want to join/weave the string and the block word by line such that the new block looks like this:

```
This is the first string of another block of strings.
Use

This is the second string of another block of strings.
three

This is the third string of another block of strings.
words.
```

What I do so far is

```
:'<,'>s/\s/\r\r\r
```

where `'<,'>s` is a range spanning the string `Use three words.`. This will give me each word of the string on a new line:

```
Use


three


words.
```

Then I use `Ctrl+v` to select the block, copy it and paste it such that I get:

```
This is the first string of another block of strings.
Use
     This is the second string of another block of strings.
three
     This is the third string of another block of strings.
words.
```

And the I manually bring it into the shape I need with a lot if `v`, `w` and `x` usage.

How can I do this more efficiently with simple copy and paste instructions in vim?

Comment: Just a heads up there is a beta vi/vim stackexchange that started up recently : http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cheers, that's good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop-ship text from the cut buffer with swap-pasting -- pasting into a selection swaps, so `dwVP` line-deletes everything but the deleted word.

Start with

```
Use three words.
This is the first string of another block of strings.
This is the second string of another block of strings.
This is the third string of another block of strings.
```

and do

```
:normal ggdd    " three-word line in the cut buffer, cursor on first "This" line
:normal pdwVPo<ESC>j  " dwVP is cut a word and exchange-paste it back for the rest of the line
:normal pdwVPo<ESC>j  " do it again
:normal pdwVPo<ESC>j  " again
```

For just three I wouldn't qq that but `ggddqqpdwVPo<ESC>jq@q@@` is shorter.

Comment: I have never come across the swap-pasting `VP` method you used, nice to know. Is this anywhere documented in the help?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Well, [here's a guy from 2011 complaining it's a bug](http://superuser.com/questions/321547/how-do-i-replace-paste-yanked-text-in-vim-without-yanking-the-deleted-lines) :-) ... The only place I ever recall seeing this was in a *.SO post somewhere I can't find atm.  `:help p` sure doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: >5min see `:help put-Visual-mode`, the per-command docs don't mention it but reading all of the `copy-move` section gets  you there. I think I picked this up for a *.SO post somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would start like you do by splitting the sentence up into new lines but after that I would

- Number each line for both blocks
- Paste one part completely to the other
- sort on number
- remove the numbers

This could look like this

- *Blok1* - `:%s/\s/\r/g`
- *Blok1* - `%s/^/\=line('.')*1000+1`
- *Blok2* - `%s/^/\=line('.')*1000`
- Copy entire *Blok2* into buffer of *Blok1*
- `sort n`
- `%s/\v^\d+`